# How do I use the RandomRangedNumberCustomization in Autofixture to ensure parameters are in a certain range?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I have a class that takes two parameters as shown:

```
    public double X { get; private set; }

    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        if (x > 90 || x < -90)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("latitude");

        if (y > 180 || y < -180)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("longitude");

        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
```

The corresponding properties are set in the constructor, so I need to tell AutoFixture to create a Point class with parameters in the range as specified in the guard clauses.  I have managed to get a bit confused about the usage of the RandomRangedNumberCustomization class.  I did the following:

```
        var xRange = new RangedNumberRequest(typeof(double), -90.0, 90.0);
        var yRange = new RangedNumberRequest(typeof (double), -180.0, 180.0);
        var dummyContext = new DelegatingSpecimenContext();
        var generator = new RandomRangedNumberGenerator();
        var x = (double)generator.Create(latitudeRange, dummyContext);
        var y = (double) generator.Create(longitudeRange, dummyContext);
```

which will generate numbers in my range, so I could just create a Point and feed in those generated numbers, but I'm missing something in terms of the customization.  Any help and or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the solutions suggested by Nikos Baxevanis, here's another option. You can implement a convention that always handles the `x` and `y` arguments for `Point` in a particular way:

```
public class PointCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new XBuilder());
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new YBuilder());
    }

    private class XBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            var pi = request as ParameterInfo;
            if (pi == null ||
                pi.Name != "x" ||
                pi.Member.DeclaringType != typeof(Point))
                return new NoSpecimen(request);

            return context.Resolve(
                new RangedNumberRequest(typeof(double), -90d, 90d));
        }
    }

    private class YBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            var pi = request as ParameterInfo;
            if (pi == null ||
                pi.Name != "y" ||
                pi.Member.DeclaringType != typeof(Point))
                return new NoSpecimen(request);

            return context.Resolve(
                new RangedNumberRequest(typeof(double), -180d, 180d));
        }
    }
}
```

(There's room for refactoring in the above code.)

Given `PointCustomization`, this test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void CreatePointDoesNotThrow()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new PointCustomization());
    var e = Record.Exception(() => fixture.Create<Point>());
    Assert.Null(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I like using conventions and have used them in the past.  I was looking at the RangedNumber classes and wasn't certain of the best way to use them, so this helped.  I'm still not sure how to use the RandomRangedNumberCustomization, of if it has application in my particular situation.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a couple of ways of customizing AutoFixture for this. – Here are a few of them:

**With Data Annotations**

```
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(
        [Range( -90,  90)]double x,
        [Range(-180, 180)]double y)
    {
        if (x > 90 || x < -90)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("latitude");

        if (y > 180 || y < -180)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("longitude");

        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

[Fact]
public void CreatePointDoesNotThrow()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => fixture.Create<Point>()); // Passes.
}
```

**With Generators**

```
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        if (x > 90 || x < -90)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("latitude");

        if (y > 180 || y < -180)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("longitude");

        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

[Fact]
public void CreatePointDoesNotThrow()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var x = new Generator<int>(fixture).First(pt => pt >  -90 && pt <  90);
    var y = new Generator<int>(fixture).First(pt => pt > -180 && pt < 180);
    fixture.Customize<Point>(c => c
        .FromFactory(() => new Point(x, y)));

    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => fixture.Create<Point>()); // Passes.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm not a big fan of data annotations, but they are handy.  I liked your idea about using the Generator, which was new for me so thanks for that as well.  Ultimately I like conventions, so I accepted Mark's answer, but yours was an excellent idea as well, and I plan to use it use for one-off tests when I don't need a whole convention.